# Automated replace of sprintf function with c++ string functions

Tags: c++, string, emacs, sed, text-editor

We have a large amount of "demo" code that uses sprintf and cstrings to construct filenames. I'd like to replace it with c++ strings  to allow very long filenames and because it gives a cleaner syntax.

So essentially we need to convert blocks like

```
ofstream some_file;
char filename[100];
sprintf(filename,"%s/soln%i.dat",a.c_str(), b);
some_file.open(filename);
```

into something like

```
ofstream some_file((a + "soln" + to_string(b) + ".dat").c_str());
```

However because this is used in a lot of places I'd like to use some kind of automatic conversion (i.e. sed expressions, emacs function/macros, visual studio?, etc.). The difficulties (that I can see) are:

1. The contents of the sprintf statement can be anything. (So we need to parse an sprintf statement?)
2. some_file and filename could be declared anywhere, could be named anything and often are reused for output to multiple files. (So we need to parse C++?)

Is this possible/feasible?

For bonus points can we avoid having to call .c_str() on the string (without changing the ofstream constructor)?

Comment: You can avoid the `.c_str()` by using a modern compiler.

Comment: `boost::format` uses the same format strings as `sprintf`

Comment: Presumably you mean use c++11? We don't use it because of worries about unimplemented features in the compilers of some supercomputers.

Comment: So the real problem here is that the buffer you are writing to is fixed in size.  Keep it simple, and replace printf with a function that outputs to a std::string and otherwise keeps the same arguments and types, and replace filename with a std::string?  Exactly how many places where the old pattern is being used, and how close are they to being exactly the same pattern?  A not completely automated version would be to globally search & replace every printf in your code with the string_printf that refuses to take a char* or char[] as argument 1, compile, and fix all the errors resulting...

Comment: boost::format looks interesting but we currently don't use anything from boost so I'm not sure it's worth the additional dependency.

Comment: boost is like the second half of the Standard Library, it's always worth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something simpler, w/o Yassnippet:

```
(defun sprintf-to-ofstream (file)
  (interactive "sFile to print to: ")
  (back-to-indentation)
  (let* ((start (point))
         arglist
         sprintf-args
         ofstream-args
         (end 
          (save-excursion
            (move-end-of-line 1)
            (point)))
         (line (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)))
    (unless (string= (substring line 0 7) "sprintf")
      (error "No `sprintf' at this line"))
    (setq arglist
          (split-string
           (substring line (1+ (position ?\( line))
                      (position ?\) line :from-end t))
           "\\s-*,\\s-*")
          sprintf-args
          (split-string (substring (cadr arglist) 1 -1)
                        "%[^[:alpha:]%#]*[[:alpha:]%#]")
          ofstream-args
          (with-output-to-string
            (princ (concat "\"" (car sprintf-args) "\""))
            (setq sprintf-args (cdr sprintf-args))
            (dotimes (i (length sprintf-args))
              (princ " + ")
              (when (< (+ i 2) (length arglist))
                (princ (nth (+ i 2) arglist))
                (princ " + "))
              (princ (concat "\"" (nth i sprintf-args) "\"")))))
    (kill-region start end)
    (insert (concat "ofstream " file "((" ofstream-args ").c_str());" ))))
```

You could bind it to any key you like and use like so:

- Move the point to the line containing `sprintf` you want to replace, for example by doing <kbd>M-%</kbd>`sprintf`, then call this function. It will prompt you to give it the name of the file where you want to print the message (probably I could make it more complex, and search upwards for the place where ofstream was declared, but if you say it may have been declared in an arbitrary place, that sounds like a wasted effort).
- Press <kbd>RET</kbd>, after this the function will change the line to looks something like:

```
ofstream foo(("" + a.c_str() + "/soln" + b + ".dat").c_str());
```

given your original example. Obviously, if you think that adding a `to_string()` around arguments is more likely to be the case, then it is easy to do, given some more effort it will be also easy to avoid concatenating empty strings too, but some times it may change the effect / interpretation of the `+` operator, so I decided to keep it like this. I'll try to make it into a yassnippet script a bit later today, so that it would be possible to jump to uncertain places in the replaced string interactively and have some pre-defined replacements too.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much exactly what I was thinking of. I tweaked it a little to work on a complete c++ statement (point until the first ";") and wrote a function to do some search replacing to clean up other bits.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library. It implements printf-type formats in C++, producing C++ strings as output. The invocation is similar, but slightly different. Your example would be:

```
string fname = boost::format("%s/soln%i.dat") % a % b;
ofstream some_file(fname.c_str());
```

So basically, you would need to identify the char buffer, and replace it with a string; identify the sprintf statement, tokenize it into arguments (while taking care with quotation marks etc.), and rewrite it using % instead of , with the first argument wrapped in boost::format. Sounds a bit daunting, but not impossible. A bigger problem is that your blocks may not all look like that, and identifying these situations in general would be very hard.

Comment: On my system you need to enclose the RHS in `boost::str` otherwise you get an error.